# How to extract the 4th character must be number in the column

Tags: postgresql

I want to select the column which has 4th character is number.
example:

```
column
----------
Game1234 
nothing12
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the SQL you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: i expect  if 4th character is a number then it should be the result for my statement.

Comment: In your example no record has a number at the forth position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=759d164d11351529f2b2a25fee6512a2)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE substring(col, 4, 1) ~ '[0-9]'
```

1. `substring()` extracts a certain substring (in this case from the 4th position a substring with length 1)
2. `~ '[0-9]'` checks if the extracted character is a digit (using regular expressions)

Comment: this is what i want exactly , thanks  for your kindness.

Answer (score 1):

More efficient would be:

```
substr(col, 4, 1) BETWEEN '0' and '9'
```

Comment: Thanks sir, it also gives me a expected resul. 

Comment: Regular expressions are expensive.